# Determine if two objects contain references to the same object

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to determine if the fields within an object contain any pointer aliasing?

For example:

```
class A {
    A a1;
    A a2;
}

A z = new A();

A y = new A();
y.a1 = z;
y.a2 = z;

A x = new A();
x.a1 = y;
x.a2 = z;

// i.e. x has a reference to y and to z, and y has a reference to z
```

In this example I want to determine that object x contains pointer aliasing since x.a1.a1 == x.a2

The idea I have is to use reflection to iterate the reference fields of the object, and for each field, build a set of references by traversing through each field storing references as I go (i.e. flatten each reference into a set of references). I would then look at the intersection of these sets.
Is this a good solution to my question?

Comment: What do you mean by *intersection of these sets*?

Comment: How you use x.a1 = z before x object is created

Comment: Your approach sounds reasonable ... good to see that you are thinking about what you are asked to do and then about how in algorithmic terms before jumping in to implementation.

Comment: Use an `IdentityHashSet`?

Comment: @Youngistan sorry I corrected the code in the question

Comment: I'll show you a tricky way to find out: Inside class `A`, create a `String` instance variable. After each assignment, assign the string to the name of object that you referenced to.

Comment: Let me see if I understand; you want to check, when you have an instance, whether you can, via chaining, obtaining `a2` from `a1`?

Comment: Note that this is essentially the same navigation as object serialization (enumerate all the objects in a dependency tree, while recognizing loops and avoiding being trapped by them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your need correctly, what you need here is an `IdentityHashSet`:

```
public static boolean hasLoops(final A a)
{
    if (a.a2 == null)
         return false;
    final Set<A> set = new IdentityHashSet<>();
    set.add(a.a2);
    A other = a.a1;
    while (other != null) {
        if (!set.add(other))
            return true;
        other = other.a1;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Since you want equality for the same references, an `IdentityHashSet` is what you want; although if you don't implement `.equals()` or `.hashCode()`, a "regular" `HashSet` can also do the trick.